# How do I insert a greek character along with a variable text string in matlab plot?

Tags: string, matlab, latex

I tried:

```
txt = text(0.05, 21, texlabel(['d = ' num2str(d_close) 'mu m']));
```

But this did not worked. The variable part comes out well, but "mu m" do not turn out into their greek form. I want latex greek variant of mu and  latex variant of m. mu m  = micrometre.

**Update:** I got it to work partly

```
txt = text(0.05, 21, (['d = ' num2str(d_close), '\mum']));
txt.FontSize = 24;
```

But, "m" does not look like a mathematical character as it looks neat in latex. Here in Matlab it looks like just a regular alphabetic letter. I wish mu and m to appear as they appear from latex coding $\mu m$ in the respective pdf file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the interpretor to LaTeX and then use your typical LaTeX notation with

```
txt = text(0.05, 21, ("d = " + d_close + "$\mu m$"),'Interpreter','latex');
```

Note that as the notation includes dollarsigns `$$` you have to use strings `"text"` rather than character arrays `'text'` and strings are joined by using `"s"+"t"` rather than `['s','t']`.

Comment: Thank you Nicky. I was doing hard-coding earlier. txt = text(0.03, 21.5,'$$d = 33 \mu m$$', 'interpreter','latex');  But now you made it easier for me. Many thanks.

Comment: @Vikash Glad to be of help. Please consider accepting the answer (by clicking the checkmark), this will keep the amount of unanswered questions low and it supports me.